# css transform:scale(2,2) pops up behind other images

Tags: html, css, transform, scale, z-order

I'm using Joomla 3.3 and, on mouseover I want to enlarge an image.

The html for the image is:

```
<img class="enlarge" style="float: right; margin: 10px; border: 5px solid black;" title="Chapter 1: Physical Differences" src="images/chapters/chapter-1-physical-differences.jpg" alt="Chapter 1: Physical Differences" width="311" height="390" />
```

To affect the enlargement on mouseover I'm using the following CSS:

```
.enlarge:hover {
    transform:scale(2,2);
    transform-origin:0 0;
}
```

It works great BUT, on the right side of the page there is a smaller image and  the large image pops up under smaller image on the screen... it's like I need to set the z-index but I tried that and that didn't change the results at all.

Before:[image]

Mouseover:
[image]

Comment: More HTML/CSS (reproducing your issue) is required to help you create your desired behaviour.

Comment: Apply `transform:scale(1.001)` to the other image or something like that

Answer (score 2):

z-index doesn't affect display: static elements. I believe the issue you are outlining is that your floated image has simply been added to the DOM before the smaller image, such that it will always appear behind the other image.

So I suspect you will have to do one of the following:

1. an order of operations that adds the smaller image before the larger image.
2. hide the smaller image when the larger image is moused over.
3. set the smaller image to something like display: absolute, and then set a lower z-index.
4. Hacky stuff like remove the smaller image after DOM load and then re-add it to change it's default z-order.
5. make the larger image not a float, and allow it's change in size to push the smaller image to the next line.

That's all I can come up with off of the top of my head. :-)

Comment: That sounds suspiciously correct... and probably explains why my limited CSS skills got me nowhere! Unfortunately, using Joomla, I don't have control over the load order.  Also, if I don't float the image I don't think I can get it to sit to the right of the text and and I don't want to hard code it and loose my support for mobile devices.